# Random start in Android video app

Tags: android, video, random

I have this video app:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int i = 0;
    List<String> videoPathes = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    private VideoView videoview;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView_video);
        videoPathes.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/intros/intro1.mp4");
        videoPathes.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/intros/intro2.mp4");
        videoPathes.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/intros/intro3.mp4");

        videoview.setVideoPath(videoPathes.get(i));
        videoview.start();

        videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp){
                i = (i + 1) % videoPathes.size();

                videoview.setVideoPath(videoPathes.get(i));
                videoview.start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

When the app starts run the first video ("intro1.mp4"). The app has 20 videos. What I need is that when I open the application, it starts playing random video.

Example:

**Now**

> The app starts with the first video: "intro1.mp4" then continues to "intro2.mp4" and >"intro3.mp4". (etc...)

**I need**

> Start with random video: "intro2.mp4", "intro3.mp4", "intro1.mp4"
>
> The second time: "intro1.mp4", "intro2.mp4", "intro3.mp4"
>
> Next time: "intro3.mp4", "intro1.mp4", "intro2.mp4"
>
> (etc...)

So, start with any video (intro11.mp4) and continue with the next (intro12.mp4), and next (intro13.mp4), and next (intro14.mp4).

Is this possible with my app?

Thanks for any support.

Comment: Well instead of `i = (i + 1) % videoPathes.size();` on completion, you'll need to track the previous values of `i` so you don't repeat, and instead calculate the next `i` value using Random. Tracking between runs of the program, however, will have to involve some sort of inter-session tracking (serialization, database, etc.).

Comment: Thanks but I do not need something as complex. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create list of videos where the order is random.
not compiled code:

```
List randomList = new ArrayList();
Random random = new Random();
int pathsCount = videoPathes.size();
for (int i = 0; i < pathsCount; i++){
 int randomPathIndex = random.nextInt(videoPathes.size();
 String path = videoPathes.get(randomPathIndex));
 videoPathes.remove(randomPathIndex);
 randomList.add(path);
}
```

I think this should work :)

Comment: Just before videoview.setVideoPath(videoPathes.get(i));
Instead of using videoPathes u use randomList after that.